# Places Autocomplete Api Parameters

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

Google Places Autocomplete Api has multiple parameters as listed here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

I need to know if it is required to set "radius" parameter when I use "location" parameter?
Can I use "location" only and omit "radius"?

You get a response, but it is diffcult to verify if results are actually biased to this location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a `radius` then the API will ignore `location`, and the results you get won't be biased to that location, but to the user's location (from their IP address).

This call (with `location` set within San Francisco, without `radius`):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&key=KEY
```

And this other call (without `location` nor `radius`):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&key=KEY
```

Return the same (unbiased) place results; the first result is "Amoeba Music, Sunset Boulevard, Los Angeles, CA, USA".

You can only bias results if you use both `location` and `radius`, like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=1000&key=KEY
```

Notice how this third call returns "Amoeba Music, Haight Street, San Francisco, CA, USA" first.

Hope this helps!